# does sum() take the execution time of a loop in python3

Tags: python-3.x, execution-time

I used `sum()` in a loop and it take more than 4s to execute, is the `sum()` equal to nested loop here?

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    cop=k
    lis=[]
    i=0
    while i < len(inputArray):
        inpu=sum(inputArray[i:cop])
        lis.append(inpu)
        cop+=1
        i+=1
    return max(lis)
```

Comment: Each ``sum`` call iterates over all elements of its entire argument once - otherwise, it could not *sum* up those elements. What exactly is unclear to you about how ``sum`` works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sum` is implemented as a C++ library, so it is still going to be faster than a Python for-loop, although you're still running nested loops either way. To illustrate, I timed your code here, as well as a modified code that uses a Python loop instead:

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSumLoop(inputArray, k):
    cop=k
    lis=[]
    i=0
    while i < len(inputArray) - k:
        inpu = 0
        for j in range(i, cop):  # for-loop in place of sum
            inpu += inputArray[j]
        lis.append(inpu)
        cop += 1
        i += 1
    return max(lis)
```

The timings were:

```
arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(np.random.rand(10000), 100)
111 ms ± 1.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

arrayMaxConsecutiveSumLoop(np.random.rand(10000), 100)
198 ms ± 4.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

so the implementation with `sum` (your version) is faster by about a factor of two!

### Better implementation

I rewrote your function using `numpy` to make it *way* faster! This implementation has no nested loops and is O(n), as well as being implemented with the very fast numpy libraries.

```
import numpy as np
def array_max_consecutive_sum(input_array, k):
    result = np.cumsum(input_array)
    return max(result[k:] - result[:-k])

array_max_consecutive_sum(np.random.rand(10000), 100)
688 µs ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

That's more than 150 times faster!

### Other options

Incidentally, the accepted answer (as of this writing) gives timing:

```
6.46 ms ± 147 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Fast, but still only a tenth as fast as the numpy implementation above. Also, the result is wrong.

Comment: How did you calculate the timings?

Comment: Why the zip? just use `dd = lambda x,y: max(sum(x[i:i+y])for i in range(len(x)-y+1))` and now time it

Comment: @Onyambu good solution! I changed my rewritten code anyway though. Got it working a *lot* faster with numpy.

Comment: @AnilRedshift If you are using Jupyter, you can just execute a line with `%timeit my_function_here(args)` or a whole cell by putting `%%timeit` (two percent-signs) at the top. It will handle running multiple loops and calculating the timing for you.

Comment: sorry not familiar with numpy yet..i did though

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in order to add all the elements together, `sum` code must traverse the  `inputArray` (from i to cop).

Additionally, `len(inputArray)` must also traverse the entire array to get its length. Thus, your solution is O(n*k)

You can optimize your code to an O(n) solution with the following:

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    max = sum(inputArray[0:k])
    bucket = max
    count = len(inputArray)
    for i in range(1, 1 + count - k):
        prev = inputArray[i - 1]
        cur = inputArray[i + k - 1]
        bucket += cur - prev
        if bucket > max:
            max = bucket
    return max
```

This algorithm only loops over the array once. Imagine having a fixed bucket sliding down an line. As you increment i, the bucket needs to take the most recent item, but the oldest item drops off the back. Using this logic, you only need to look at each item at most twice - when you add it to the bucket, and when you remove it out the other end.

** Please note that special case handling is omitted for the sake of clarity**

Comment: sorry but this is not what OP is doing. OP is doing rolling sums.. your code is doing something completely different.. you are adding to the max??? also note that your range is wrong

Comment: Your result isn't the same as his on my test case. I used a random array, so the values are meaningless and yours will be different, but if you run his and yours with the same inputs, you will see.

Comment: your range is wrong. you are leaving out the very last element from the computation ie: you should use `range(1, count - k+1)`

Comment: "``len(inputArray)`` must also traverse the entire array to get its length" - that is false. All standard Python containers store their length.